# Plotting 2D graph using inequality Equation

Tags: javascript, graph, html5-canvas, createjs

how to plot graph in canvas using inequality equation e.g. y>3x-1 ? considering our canvas consist of cartesian coordinate of 20 by 20 (-10 to 10).i have calculated the polygon by placing the values of end points of canvas.for y>3x-1. we have get four points (-10,10),**(-10,-10),(-3,-10),(3.67,10).but i am unable to sort and shade this polygon. Can you tell me any approach regarding this. it would be a great help. Thanx in advance.